# Trying to connect a QnA knowledgebase in the new BotframeWork Composer

Tags: botframework, bots

I'm currently playing around with the new composer. I'm now trying to connect a knowledge base in the composer. I added the following in the composer  [image: I added the following] And filled everything in in my settings. [image: settings] But when i call this `dialog` i get this visual response from the bot [image: this visual response] and this in the trace of the `emulator`

[image: the trace]

Kindly guide me how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Is your QnA knowledge base trained and published? And, did you follow all of the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/blob/stable/docs/how-to-add-qna-to-bot.md)?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved.
It is a known bug in BotFramework Composer as you can see here [Officiel Composer Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/1517)